# Issue while pushing data from PySpark to RedShift

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-redshift

I have a dataframe which I'm trying to write it into a redshift table. I have given all the authentication credentials to connect to redshift and S3 from Spark.
Below is the code.

```
    joinedDf.registerTempTable("mytable1")
    jdbcURL = "jdbc:redshift://server:port/db?user=username&password=password"
    tempS3Dir = "s3://bucket url"
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "Access KEY ID")
    sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "Secret Access KEY")
    spark.sql("SELECT * FROM mytable1") \
    .write \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", jdbcURL) \
    .option("tempdir", tempS3Dir) \
    .option("dbtable", "mytable") \
    .option("aws_iam_role", "arn of RedShift") \
    .mode('append') \
    .save()
```

However, I'm getting below error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        ... 35 more
```

It seems that issue is with missing jar, however, while launching the spark application, I have included required jars.

```
spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--driver-class-path /home/hadoop/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar,RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar,spark-redshift_2.11-3.0.0-preview1.jar,aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.8.jar,aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.8.jar,hadoop-aws-2.7.0.jar,hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar \
--jars /home/hadoop/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar,RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.10.1009.jar,spark-redshift_2.11-3.0.0-preview1.jar,aws-java-sdk-core-1.9.8.jar,aws-java-sdk-s3-1.9.8.jar,hadoop-aws-2.7.0.jar,hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar \
/home/hadoop/code.py
```

Can someone help me out with it? Or, is there any other tried and tested solution for same.?
Btw,it's a single node cluster in AWS EMR and  **PySpark Verion is 2.2**

Comment: taking a step back and looking at the overall process, are you hoping to insert high volumes from pyspark into redshift?

Comment: @JonScott: As of now it's around 2 GB of data which I'm trying to push. This number get's increased by 200 Mb per day.